# drop down to refresh values based on the selected value in another drop down in angular in individual component

Tags: angular

I Have a scenerio which i have given below. I am using the latest version of angular 9 and node js

I have child component called 'cities' which contains a drop down having some important cities like for example- Chennai, Delhi, Bangalore.

I have another child component called 'areas' which contains a drop down based on the selected city in the another drop down. For example if i select 'Bangalore' i would like to display 'area1' and 'area2'. If i select 'Chennai' then i would like to display 'area3' and 'area4'.

Below is the code of app-component

```
<app-city></app-city>
<app-area></app-area>
```

Below is the code of app-city (template)

```
<label>City: </label>
  <select (change)="onCityClick()">
    <option value="0">--All--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let city Of cities" value={{city.cityId}}>
      {{city.cityName}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Below is the code of city component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { city } from './city';
import { CityService } from './city.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-city',
  templateUrl: './city.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city.component.css']
})
export class CityComponent implements OnInit {

  cities : Array<city> = [];
  constructor(private cityService : CityService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cities = this.cityService.getCities();
  }

  onCityClick(){
    console.log('need to get the city id here');
  }
}
```

Below is the code of city service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { city } from './city'


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class CityService {

    constructor() { }

    getCities()  {

      let cities : Array<city> = [];

            // sample json data which retuns a collection of cities from service
            const objcity = new city();
            objcity.cityId = 1;
            objcity.cityName = 'bangalore';
            cities.push(objcity);

            const objcity1 = new city();
            objcity1.cityId = 2;
            objcity1.cityName = 'chennai';
            cities.push(objcity1);



      return cities;
    }
  }
```

Below is the city object

```
export class city{
    cityId: number;
    cityName: string;
}
```

Below is code of app-area (template)

```
<label>City: </label>
  <select (change)="onCityClick()">
    <option value="0">--All--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let city Of cities" value={{city.cityId}}>
      {{city.cityName}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

Below is the code of area - component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AreaService } from './area.service';
import { area } from './area';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-area',
  templateUrl: './area.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./area.component.css']
})
export class AreaComponent implements OnInit {

  areas : Array<area> = [];
  constructor(private  areaService: AreaService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.areas =  this.areaService.getAreas(1);
  }

  onAreaClick(){
    console.log('-- need to get the area id here ');
  }
}
```

Below is the code of area service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { area } from './area'


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class AreaService {

    constructor() { }

    getAreas(cityId : number)  {

      let areas : Array<area> = [];
      // @ts-ignore


            // sample json data which retuns a collection of areas based on the cityId from service
            const objarea = new area();
            objarea.areaId = 1;
            objarea.areaName = 'areaa1';
            areas.push(objarea);

            const objarea1 = new area();
            objarea1.areaId = 2;
            objarea1.areaName = 'area2';
            areas.push(objarea1);

      return areas;
    }
  }
```

Below is the class of area

```
export class area{
    areaId: number;
    areaName: string
}
```

Problem 1. To get the Selected value of the city on the click event
Problem 2. To pass the Cityid to the area service to fetch data based on the cityId
Problem 3. to reload the dropdown of areas based on the recent selection.

Let me know if there is a better approach from the above code and how to fix the issue.

Comment: Can  you create a stackblitz instance with the code you have written?

Comment: Use an event emitter to get the selected city and pass it as input to the second component. You can use ngOnchanges to update list.

Comment: can i get the implemtation using ngOnchanges

Answer (score 0):

You have your two components

```
@Component({
  selector: "city-select",
  template: `
    <label for="cars">Choose a city:</label>

    <select
      id="cars"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
      (ngModelChange)="onCityChange()"
    >
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
      <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
      <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    </select>
  `
})
export class CitySelectComponent {
  @Output() selectCity: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  private selectedCity = "";

  private onCityChange() {
    this.selectCity.emit(this.selectedCity);
  }
}
```

And

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello Angular!</h1><p>Welcome to {{city}}.</p>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() city: string;
}
```

You have an "app" component which renders your two components

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <hello [city]="cityName"></hello>
    <city-select (selectCity)="onSelectCity($event)"></city-select>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public cityName = "";

  public onSelectCity(city: string) {
    this.cityName = city;
  }
}
```

Problem 1 is solved by two-way binding using [ngModel](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel-two-way-binding).

Problem 2 is solved by:

1. Using ngModelChange to listen for changes to the selectedCity value.
2. We have a property called selectCity with the [@Output](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#how-to-use-output)
   decorator, which is an EventEmitter that emits our selected city.
3. We can then use event binding to listen for this event in our "app"
   component. You would use the onSelectCity function to send the
   cityId to your area service to retrieve your areas.

Problem 3 is solved by using the [@Input](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#how-to-use-input) decorator, we can recieve our selected city from our "app" component into our "hello" component. You would get the list of areas from your parent component into your child component.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/difference-between-change-and-ngmodelchange-in-angular . this articles shows that ngmodel is deprectated. I am using angular latest verison. I am not sure if there could be a better approach

Comment: @jaiangular It is deprecated for [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularforms). We're using [two-way-binding](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-ngmodel-on-a-standalone-control) to keep our value and view in sync.